# How to draw 3 overlapping circles with different colors?

Tags: gimp, inkscape, drawing, open-source

Is there a free software to draw following in ubuntu? How to color the overlap zone? I am not able to figure this out in GIMP.

[image]

Comment: AKA [Venn diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Inkscape.](http://www.inkscape.org/) Basically, you’ll have to break the circles into several parts, one for each possible intersection of circles:

1. Select two circles you want to create the intersection for.
2. Use `Object → Intersection` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>*</kbd>) to create the intersection.
3. Copy the intersection to the clipboard (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>).
4. Undo the intersection operation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>), which deletes the intersection object and restores the original circles.
5. Paste the intersection object *in place* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, **not** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>).
6. Colour the intersection.
7. Repeat steps 1–6 for the remaining pairs of circles, and again on the three two-circle intersections (to create the middle intersection).

You might also want to use the difference operator (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>) on the outer circles to cut out the shape of the inner parts.

Comment: Sorry - since there are compositing operations both in inkscape and GIMP to allow circle sobreposition, and since in the the software the OP is actually using, GIMP, using an arbitrary color is trivial using selector by color, I find this way overly complicated.

Comment: Why don't you just copy in step 2, intersect in step 3 and jump to 6 - color the intersection? What's the use of using clipboard and undo?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed this is possible in gimp pretty easily.

1. Create three circles with colors #ff0000, #00ff00 and #0000ff each to own layer with transparent background
2. Add black background layer
3. Position those circles as in your image
4. Use Additive Blending mode for all of them (i.e. open "Edit layer attributes", select "Mode" | "Legacy" and then "Addition")
5. Just remove black background if necessary

Comment: i want to color the overlap zone with any color not necessarily what will result from color addition.

Comment: Ah, sorry somehow i misread what you wrote. Anyway you can use the method I posted above and afterwards just merge all the layers and use smart select tool to select center and then recolor it to anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you have PowerPoint 2013, you can use the fragment tool to quickly create the individual pieces that you can then freely format as you see fit. See below tutorial.

[PowerPoint 2013 Venn Diagram Tutorial - The Middle Piece](http://youtu.be/ReQBlmaZb-E)

Comment: Daaang! tossing PowerPoint into the mix.. brave man.